# How To Build Xapian 1.4.10 with MSVC2017?

Tags: visual-c++, xapian

I had install MSVC2017,zlib,msys2. 
Run configure in msys2 and have some error:
  ./configure CC="cl -nologo" CXX="$PWD/compile cl -nologo" CXXFLAGS=-EHsc AR=lib

configure: loading site script /etc/config.site
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... no
checking whether make supports nested variables... no
checking whether UID '1492654' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking whether GID '1049089' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... pax
checking for style of include used by make... none
checking for gcc... cl -nologo
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/d/xapian_proj/xapian-core-1.4.10':

configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables

See`config.log' for more details

Thanks

Comment: Is it deliberate that you're using significantly different commands for CC and CXX?

Comment: @JamesAylett not find the C compiler,maybe the CXX will not find too